# Nginx configuration for multiple servers in folders

Tags: nginx

I have just installed Nginx on my Raspberry and everything works smoothly.

I have created a basic index.html file and when I connect to my raspi, the web page is displayed correctly. Also php works.

I would like now to create a couple of projects as subdirectory of the /var/www default directory, project automation (/var/www/automation) and project information (/var/www/information), each 3 independent from the other.

So when connecting with the raspiIP (192.168.0.1), I would like to display the main or default website.

Then when connecting to raspiIP/automation, I would like to display the site dedicated to the automation and finally when connecting to rapiIP/information, I would like to display a third web site.

How can I configure nginx to achieve that?

I have tried what explained about Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) but I have gone nowhere.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks, daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to serve those folders would be to simply move them under the default webroot (`/var/www/html`?). You don't need to create any special configuration to serve subfolders.

You will really only need to configure additional server blocks for anything under a different domain or subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, clear, it works. So I have a doubt. What are additional server blocks for? What is their purpose? Thanks, daniele

Comment: I use additional server blocks to serve other domains and/or subdomains: for example a server block each for `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, and `c.example.com`. Each can be configured with its own web root or set up as a proxy to another service. It's super flexible.